# Given a sphere and its dV/dt, and the pressure on the sphere along with the dP/dt, how could I find the volume of the sphere?

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I'm given a sphere (of gas) which is being squished and told its volume is decreasing at a rate 10 cubic inches per second, which I know means dV/dt = -10. I'm also told that the pressure on the sphere is currently 8 lbs./sq. in., but it's increasing at a rate of 2 lbs./sq. in. per second which I understand means dP/dt = 2.

What I don't understand is how I could ever relate the pressure on the sphere to its volume. I could easily solve the problem if I knew the relation, but I just can't see how these two measurements are at all related. I've been messing around with it strenuously for a while now, I tried to relate the pressure to the surface area and I think that's on the right track, but I've had no luck because I always get stuck since I don't know the radius or how the radius changes with time. At the end of the problem, it also mentions that the product of a gas's volume and pressure is a constant when the temperature is constant (which it is in this scenario), which only serves to confuse me further because I don't see where I would multiply the volume and pressure in the problem. I've also thought about using an integral, but discarded the idea because I don't know the upper limit of the radius.

I'd prefer a hint to set me on the right track because I already know the answer as supplied by the textbook. What the textbook doesn't explain is how you actually get the answer, which is frustrating, so I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction as I'm probably just overlooking something extremely simple. The textbook is a calculus textbook, and I believe the subject of the problem is "more complicated" related rates.

Comment: is it an ideal gas? $PV=nRT$

Comment: @user619894 It is not an ideal gas, and gas laws shouldn't be relevant to the solution because it was never mentioned anywhere. It should be solvable using only calculus, as every problem has been in this textbook. I believe it being a gas is only relevant so that PV will be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PV is a constant.
$\frac{d}{dt} PV=0$
$P\frac{dV}{dt}+V\frac{dP}{dt}=0$

Answer (score 0):

First use
$$
V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3
\rightarrow
dV = 4 \pi r^2 dr
\rightarrow
V_t
= \frac{dV}{dt}
= 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}
$$
Note that $V_t$ does not depend on time
according to your problem.

From $P=F/A$, it follows
$$
dP 
= \frac{-F}{A^2} dA 
= \frac{-2F}{A^2} \cdot 4\pi r dr
= \frac{-2FV_t}{rA^2} dt
\rightarrow
P_t
= \frac{dP}{dt}
= \frac{-2FV_t}{rA^2}
$$
Note that $V_t$ does not depend on time
according to your problem.

So eliminating $F$ yields
$$
P_0
= \frac{F}{A_0}
=\frac{-P_t r_0 A_0}{2 V_t}
$$
from which you can deduce $r_0$.
Please let me know what you find and if it matches the result of your textbook.

Comment: Steph, I'm letting you know I have figured out the solution through Cineel's answer, but through your solution I get an answer of V = 26.6666... which is not the correct answer of V = 40.

Comment: @Turts $P_0=F/A_0$ this step might be problematic because the force could change with time.

Comment: Yes. I was not sure of this step too. I think the Boyle's law is indeed the way to solve this exercise.